Angular16 Maximum call size exceeded
I am trying to build a project on angular16 but whenever I do so I get the following error:
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
however whenever i run the madge --circular ./src command it tells me that there are no circular dependency found.

try finding reasons in this thread

It can be legitimately running out of memory. Keep an eye at memory usage using OS-specific utilities. If that is the case, try adding memory:
node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build project

I also had it (especially, in earlier versions of Angular) when I had library at different minor version of Angular than the project that included that library

Try to Increase the memory limit:
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096
